# Problems with importing android_gingerbread into eclipse

Tags: ros, rosjava, android, android-gingerbread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to build android app on ros. I followed the steps listed in this page:
http://answers.ros.org/question/2178/rosjavajar-missing-certain-packages#3713

When I am trying to import android_gingerbread into eclipse, I got errors in class org.ros.android.views.PublishingPreviewCallback. Eclipse has problems to resolve the type org.ros.message.std_msgs.Header.

The problem code is like this

```
**image.header.stamp** = node.getCurrentTime();
```

And the full error message from eclipse is like this:

Multiple markers at this line
- The type org.ros.message.std_msgs.Header cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- Header cannot be resolved to a type

Can anyone help with this problem?
Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29566/problems-with-importing-android_gingerbread-into-eclipse/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-03-12**:
Are you using the deb release or building rosjava from source?

**Comment by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on 2012-03-21**:
Hi! I am trying to build rosjava from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

finally with the help with these three links, i successfully import gingerbread

here is the link:

1. http://answers.ros.org/question/2178/rosjavajar-missing-certain-packages#3713
   This on gives a general idea of how to setup the environment for rosjava android development. But since rosmake does not work on the latest rosjava, i have to refer to the second link to figure out how to build rosjava
2. http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html
   With the help of this link i managed to build build rosjava. You can find the generated jar file under rosjava_core/rosjava/build/libs/rosjava-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
3. http://geus.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/starting-with-rosjava-and-image-messages/
   With this link i got my sensor message compiled and solved the problem for not being able to import org.ros.message.sensor_msgs.CameraInfo and org.ros.message.sensor_msgs.CompressedImage.

PS: Three jar files needed to be imported

1. rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/build/libs/rosjava_bootstrap-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2. rosjava_core/rosjava/build/libs/rosjava-0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
3. guava-11.0.2.jar (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) with karma: 106 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0